# Keras model predictions with strange behavior: High acc while "training=True", bad otherwise

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I'm trying to **overfit** my data with an episode based training (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06025). I've reproduced the original paper model and trained it on my data, a 900 images binary classification problem.

The loss seems to have stabilized with the overfitting I was expecting. The problem is, the model just predicts right while on **training mode**.

```
batch, label = epg.get_episode(X_train)

logits = model(batch, training=True)
# model.predict(batch) gets same result as model(batch, training=False)

print("pred:", K.eval(logits)[0, 0])
print("target:", K.eval(label)[0, 0])
```

With parameter `training=True`, I get 99.6% acc. Turning it off, I get around 30% (this is less than random hahah -binary problem).
Note that I'm not changing the data, it's the same used for training.

Looking for this issue, I found some like it, pointing to `BatchNormalization` layer, or don't pre scaling the data before predicting. That makes whole sense, but I don't know how it would be my case, since I'm using same data generator for both training `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what happened to cause this behavior, but I've managed to solve it just **training the model further** and further, observing the predictions with `training=False` becoming equal as with `True`.

I still think it has something to do with the `BatchNormalization()` layer, although it has never happened with my other models before.